# pyodbc version 4.0.30 present in Anaconda3 but not working in Python Version 3.8.3 Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pyodbc

i am new in Python and i would like to connect Python with a MS SQL Database using pyodbc module.
In Anaconda prompt when I digit: `pip list`  I can see that Is available this library pyodbc and it is specified the version 4.0.30.

The problem is that when I go to jupyter notebook (I have python version 3.8.3) I try to execute  import pyodbc and I get the error message:

> No module name 'pyodbc'

Why do I received this message if in Anaconda I have this module installed ?
How to solve this issue ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think jupyter notebook environment and conda enviroment is different. use this code to install pyodbc in jupyter notebook environment :

```
import os
os.system('pip install pyodbc')
```

or just install jupyter at conda environment.